# How many Right Rotation is need to convert a tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree, graph-theory

I select one nice interview question. Can anyone clarify it for me?

> Suppose a binary tree with 6 nodes is given, such that each node has
>   only left childs. With how many "right rotate" operations (without any left
>   rotates), we can convert this tree to a tree in which each node has only 
>   right childs?

my solution:

I think n-1 rotation is enough (by simulation), but I‌ couldent make a proof, which expert could help me for proof or idea?

Answer (score 1):

The tree starts with a `root` node and 5 children (which is `n-1` children) to the left. Each rotation around the `root` increases the number of children on the right by 1. So after 5 rotations (meaning `n-1` rotations) all of the children will be on the right.

**Proof by induction:** propose that after `n` rotations there are `n` children on the right.

Step 1: After 1 rotation there is 1 child on the right.

Step 2: Assume that after `n` rotations there are `n` children on the right, and prove that after `n+1` rotations, there are `n+1` children on the right.

[image]

Comment: a proof can be added?

Comment: it's true for all tree with n nodes?

Comment: That's a different question. It's certainly not true for trees where the root node starts with a right child.

Comment: I think r in the second figure must be changed to root.

Comment: in the first figure you have L,R, Root. in the second you have L,R,r

Comment: If all the children start out on the right, it still takes *at most* n-1 rotations, right?

Comment: @user4249446 The `root` in the first figure becomes `r` in the second figure. I changed the name because that node can no longer be properly called the root.

Comment: dfeuer My guess is that the number of rotations needed for any tree of `n` nodes is *at most* `n-1` rotations. I think that the actual number is `n-m` where `m` is the number of nodes arranged down the right edge. For example, given a balanced tree with 7 nodes, there are three nodes on the right edge, and it takes 4 rotations to arrange the tree as a right-only tree. This may be difficult to prove in general, compared to the question which has a very simple tree structure.